# Vector of Arguments of list of functions

Tags: r

I want to create a function where one enters a function list and it returns a vector of all the arguments of all the fuctions in the list.
This is what Im trying, but I'm not getting there. Halp pls.

```
eg<-function(Function_list){
  x1<-0
  x2<-length(Function_list)
  for (d in 1:x2){
    x1<-x1+1
    d<-formalArgs(Function_list[[x1]])
    d<-append(d,d)
    print(d)}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `formalArgs` in `lapply`, `unlist` the result und return the `unique` values.

```
eg <- function(Function_list) {
  unique(unlist(lapply(Function_list, formalArgs)))
}

eg(c("ls", "lm"))
# [1] "name"        "pos"         "envir"       "all.names"   "pattern"    
# [6] "sorted"      "formula"     "data"        "subset"      "weights"    
#[11] "na.action"   "method"      "model"       "x"           "y"          
#[16] "qr"          "singular.ok" "contrasts"   "offset"      "..."
```